# Best way to send images between an Universal Application and a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, win-universal-app

Hi i'm making an aplication that takes a picture from a car and its driver and this pictures are send to a web service, i am having problems for dealing with this situation, right now i've tried to send an encoded 64 base string, but this is not working

EDIT
Here is the code that i'm using for take the picture and save it as a byte array

```
 ImageEncodingProperties format = ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg();

        //rotate and save the image
        using (var imageStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            //generate stream from MediaCapture
            await PhotoCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(format, imageStream);
            await PhotoCapture.StopPreviewAsync();

            //create decoder and encoder
            BitmapDecoder dec = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(imageStream);
            BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(imageStream, dec);

            //roate the image
            enc.BitmapTransform.Rotation = BitmapRotation.Clockwise90Degrees;

            //write changes to the image stream
            await enc.FlushAsync();
            PreviewImage = new WriteableBitmap(350, 500);
            PreviewImage.SetSource(imageStream);

        }
        CaptureElement.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Collapsed;
        using (var ms = PreviewImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        {
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            ms.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            DriverModel.Picture = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
```

When i'm doing this the array size is like 28 millions, obviusly i'm making something wrong

Comment: How it does not work?

Comment: Why base 64 string instead of a standard image encoding? For that matter, what are you actually encoding in base 64?

Comment: Why it is not working, it should work.

Comment: @Cubic the web service, only let me save an image as an byte array, Is there a better way to save images in a data base ? or maybe y should send the image encoded in a different way(i don't konw how) and parse it to a byte array in the service